# Django rest framework not work with regex validator

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my model I have a field

```
address = models.CharField(_('address'), blank=True, max_length=42, editable=False,
                                   validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex='^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$')])
```

But when I tried to apply value more then 42 symbols, I get django error:

> value too long for type character varying(42)

When I set value: `test` for example, it passes validation(but shouldn't)

My serializer is simple:

```
class KYCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: why not if `max_length=42,` ?

Comment: @BearBrown what do you mean ?

Comment: How did you check that you can set the value to `test` ? The validators are run by calling `Model.clean_fields()`. Since version 3.0, Django Rest Framework doesn't run that for you, so you have to do it explicitly in the serializer `validate()` function. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform

Comment: DRF will get the validators from the model and use them during validation. Somehow, you did not provide everything in your question and something prevents DRF to either fetch the regex or validate against it.